# Java: use enum to call set methods in class

Tags: java, enums, constructor

My class currently looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Class1 {

    private String v1;
    private String v2;
    private String v3;
    ...

    //Enum to be used to index each variable
    public enum EnumFields
   {
      ENUM_V1,
      ENUM_V2,
      ENUM_V3,
      ...
      ...
   }

   public Class1(String[] arrayStr) {
      setV1(arrayStr[EnumFields.ENUM_V1.ordinal()]);
      setV2(arrayStr[EnumFields.ENUM_V2.ordinal()]);
      setV3(arrayStr[EnumFields.ENUM_V3.ordinal()]);
       ...
  }
```

}

How can I simplify the constructor? Is there a way in which I can map the set functions to each of the enum values and call them in a for loop? If so, how?

Thanks,
Swagatika

Comment: Is it possible to make `String`'s `v1`, ..., `vN` an array of strings of length `N`?

Comment: @Alerra how will that help?

Comment: I don't know if its possible to iterate through the strings without having them in some sort of organized structure (such as an array). My best guess for this (may not be the best way) would be to create an array of the enums and the strings and iterate through those.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why does `Class1` have fields `v1`, `v2` and `v3`, instead of `String[] vs`? I currently don't see a use case where one would do this. Of course, one could use reflection, but you shouldn't use it unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Reflection` can simplify the construction. Suppose you want call `setVn` method according to the enum `EnumFields`, the method can be retrieved through `Reflection` from the class, and can be invoked.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Class1 {
    // Enum to be used to index each variable
    public enum EnumFields {
        ENUM_V1, ENUM_V2, ENUM_V3,

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        String[] arrayStr = new String[EnumFields.values().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
            arrayStr[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(arrayStr);
        System.out.println(class1.v1);
        System.out.println(class1.v2);
        System.out.println(class1.v3);
    }

    private String v1;
    private String v2;
    private String v3;

    public Class1(String[] arrayStr) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        for (EnumFields enumField : EnumFields.values()) {
            Method setMethod = Class1.class.getDeclaredMethod("setV" + (enumField.ordinal() + 1), String.class);
            setMethod.invoke(this, arrayStr[enumField.ordinal()]);
        }
    }

    private void setV1(String v) {
        this.v1 = v;
    }

    private void setV2(String v) {
        this.v2 = v;
    }

    private void setV3(String v) {
        this.v3 = v;
    }
}
```